# upgrading to yq v4 from v3 - merging YAML files

Tags: yaml, yq

I have been using yq v3 to merge yaml files using the following command.

`yq m <yaml_file> <yaml_file2> <yaml_file3>`

The command works as outlined [here](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/v/v3.x/commands/merge)

For example, let's say I have the following 3 yaml files.

training-lab-account.yml

```
account:
  alias: training-lab-account
  orgEmail: training-lab-account@example.com
  snsSubscriptions:
    - training-lab-coe-aws@example.com
network:
  vpcs:
    - cidr: 10.253.0.0/16
  snsSubscriptions:
    - training-lab-coe-aws@example.com
```

account.yml

```
---
account:
  snsSubscriptions:
    - ONE_REQUIRED@example.com
  orgEmail: REQUIRED
  orgAccountProvisioningEnabled: true
  groups:
    - name: SmileAdmins
      policies:
        - AdministratorAccess
    - name: SmileReadOnly
      policies:
        - ReadOnlyAccess
```

network.yml

```
---
network:
  snsSubscriptions:
    - ONE_REQUIRED@example.com
  vpcs:
    - vpcName: Main
      amiPipeline: false
      accountVendingMachine: false
      flowlogs: true
      transitGw: false
      maxAzs: 3
      endpoints:
        gateway:
          - name: s3
          - name: dynamodb
        interface:
          - name: ssm
```

when I execute `yq m training-lab-account.yml account.yml network.yml`, I get the following output.

```
account:
  alias: training-lab-account
  orgEmail: training-lab-account@example.com
  snsSubscriptions:
    - training-lab-coe-aws@example.com
  orgAccountProvisioningEnabled: true
  groups:
    - name: SmileAdmins
      policies:
        - AdministratorAccess
    - name: SmileReadOnly
      policies:
        - ReadOnlyAccess
network:
  vpcs:
    - cidr: 10.253.0.0/16
      vpcName: Main
      amiPipeline: false
      accountVendingMachine: false
      flowlogs: true
      transitGw: false
      maxAzs: 3
      endpoints:
        gateway:
          - name: s3
          - name: dynamodb
        interface:
          - name: ssm
  snsSubscriptions:
    - training-lab-coe-aws@example.com
```

Basically, account.yml and network.yml are merged into training-lab-account.yml without overwriting the content in training-lab-account.yml.

yq v4 doesn't support the "m" flag to merge anymore. Actually I feel like yq@4 is a brand new  piece of software and is completely different from yq@3.

Long story short, I am trying to merge using `eval-all` as outlined [here](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/commands/evaluate-all): `yq eval-all --inplace 'select(fileIndex == 0) * select(fileIndex == 1)' f1.yml f2.yml`

Unfortunately, this overwrites what's in f1.yml from f2.yml - which is not how merge behaves in yq@3.

Since yq@3 is deprecated, I need to upgrade to yq@4. I would appreciate any feedback on how to replicate the merge feature from yq@3 in yq@4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give `--inplace`, it writes the result to the first given file. Just drop that parameter.

---

**Edit:** To have the values in `training-lab-account.yml` take precedence over those in the other files, give it as last parameter. To merge the sequence values in `vpcs:`, use `*d` to enable deep array merging. Resulting command:

```
yq eval-all 'select(fileIndex == 0) *d select(fileIndex == 1) *d select(fileIndex == 2)' account.yml network.yml training-lab-account.yml
```

Comment: Adding the --inplace flag doesn't seem to work. It basically overwrites everything in the first given file.

I used this command: 
yq eval-all --inplace 'select(fileIndex == 0) * select(fileIndex == 1) * select(fileIndex == 2)' training-lab-account.yml account.yml network.yml

Comment: @Raj You should drop it, not add it.

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean by "drop it".
Would you mind typing out the actual command that I should use?

Comment: `yq eval-all 'select(fileIndex == 0) * select(fileIndex == 1)' f1.yml f2.yml` Just what you gave in the question without the `--inplace`

Comment: gotcha, didn't even realize I had `--inplace` in my original command.

Anyways, here is what I tried with the yml files from my question above:

`yq eval-all 'select(fileIndex == 0) * select(fileIndex == 1) * select(fileIndex == 2)' training-lab-account.yml account.yml network.yml`

This ends up overwriting what's already in training-lab-account.yml with what in account.yml and network.yml. I am looking for a merge - you can see the example in my question.

Comment: @Raj Ah, now I understand your problem. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your general example

`yq eval-all --inplace 'select(fileIndex == 0) * select(fileIndex == 1)' f1.yml f2.yml`

f2.yml overwrites all values that exist in f1.yml. This corresponds to yq v3 behavior of `yq m -ix f1.yml f2.yml`

If you want to keep values from f1.yml you can simply switch the order:

`yq eval-all --inplace 'select(fileIndex == 1) * select(fileIndex == 0)' f1.yml f2.yml`

Note, that we switch the order in the select command but keep the order of the given filenames. This ensures that f1.yml is the file that is rewritten in-place.

I am pretty sure, you can define the order in the select command in a way that your 3 file merge also works as you want it.